# Plotting a hat function

Tags: piecewise

I want to plot a hat function which is zero on [-1,1] except (-0.01,0.01). I have tried:

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{1 - Abs[t], -0.01 < t < 0.01}}, 0], {t, -1, 1}]
```

Its a straight line along horizontal axis.

Comment: Look up `UnitTriangle[]`.

Comment: I need the same graph but it will touch zero at -0.01 and 0.01. In unit triangle, its between -1 and 1.

Answer (score 6):

Your plot is technically OK, but you can't see the "hat" because it is too small at scale of your plot. To experiment, let's define

```
hat[a_][t_] := Piecewise[{{1. - Abs[t], -a < t < a}}, 0]
```

Then

```
Plot[hat[.2][t], {t, -1, 1}]
```

gives something easily seen

[image: hat1]

But for `hat[.01][t]`, we need to restrict the domain to make the "hat" part visible.

```
Plot[hat[.01][t], {t, -.05, .05}]
```

[image: hat2]

Answer (score 5):

Previously this answer used [`UnitTriangle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitTriangle.html) as suggested by J.M.  I just discovered [`HeavisideLambda`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeavisideLambda.html) which seems to do exactly the same thing, but is different in some way.

```
Grid[{{
   Plot[HeavisideLambda[x/.01], {x, -1, 1}],
   Plot[UnitTriangle[x/.01], {x, -1, 1}]
   }}]
```

[image]

The two plots can be made equivalent only by increasing the number of [`PlotPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html) for `UnitTriangle`.

```
Grid[{{
   Plot[HeavisideLambda[x/.01], {x, -1, 1}],
   Plot[UnitTriangle[x/.01], {x, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100]
   }}]
```

[image]

There is some difference between the two functions, but only at a very small numeric level:

```
HeavisideLambda[#/.01] - UnitTriangle[#/.01] & /@ 
 Range[-.02, .02, .0025]

(*
{0., -4.44089*10^-16, 0., 0., 0., 0., -1.11022*10^-16, 
 1.11022*10^-16, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}
*)
```

Very off-topic edit: A more interesting, but much less useful, hat function to plot:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[(1/(Sqrt[2*Pi]*σ^3))*(1 - r^2/σ^2)*Exp[-(r^2/(2*σ^2))] /. σ -> 0.7, 
  {r, -2, 2}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.6}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  {ViewCenter -> {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, ViewPoint -> {1.988, -2.698, 0.464}, 
   ViewVertical -> {0.277, -0.3854, 1.46689}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I want a hat betwen -0.01 ans 0.01 but  total range will be -1 to 1. Thats why I have posted here. I will use it for lengendre polynomials.

Comment: They are different in the same way `UnitStep[]` and `HeavisideTheta[]` are different. Whatever that means... ;)

Comment: `MexicanHatWavelet` is also fun and interesting!  (I think that's the built-in version of JasonB's last suggestion).

Answer (score 3):

Differently:

```
f = Piecewise[{{2 - (1 - x/0.01), -0.01 < x <= 0}, {1 - x/0.01, 0 < x < 0.01}}];
Plot[f, {x, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image]

```
Plot[f, {x, -0.05, 0.05}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not that the "hat" is too small to see, but that `Plot` misses it all together on its initial sampling.  `Plot` does a nice job of adaptive sampling, but its a common "gotcha" for it to fail to see small features on its initial coarse sampling.

You *can* fix this with `PlotPoints`. This generates your plot properly:

```
 Plot[Piecewise[{{1 - Abs[t], -0.01 < t < 0.01}}, 0], {t, -1, 1}, 
    PlotPoints -> 1000]
```

Kinds of an ugly brute force approach though.

For this simple example you could use `ListPlot` and basically draw the lines:

```
 ListPlot[
  {{{-1, 0}, {-.01, 0}},
      {#, 1 - Abs[#]} & /@ {-.01, 0, .01},
        {{.01, 0}, {1, 0}}},
        Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All,
            PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

[image]

Comment: One would have hoped that if `Plot` was fed a `Piecewise` function, it would be smart enough to do some data sampling in each of the regions implicit in the definition.  Maybe Wolfram will refine the algorithm at some point — it doesn't seem like it would be that hard of a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- your function is not continuous
- the hat represents in width 1% of the plot

This probably does what you are looking for:

```
  Plot[Piecewise[{{1 - Abs[t*100], -0.01 < t < 0.01}}, 0], {t, -.02, 
  0.02}]
```

[image]